# What is returned in a field when validation fails in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

We are using email validation in a program and when we unit test the invalid test always fails. We have determined that it has something to do with the validation as the email is still being assigned the bad value. What we are not sure of if this is because of the test or the validation we are using.

```
test "when email format is invalid" do
  addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
  addresses.each do |invalid_address|
   @jobboard.email= invalid_address
   @jobboard.email= false
   assert_not(@jobboard.email,"Not a valid email")
  end
end
```

The validation code

```
#validates so that no field can be left empty
validates :jobTitle, :company, :hours, :full, :partTime, :salary, :description,  :requirements, :website, :email, presence: true
validates :email, allow_blank: true, format:{
  with: %r{\w+([+.']\w+)@\w+([.]\w+)\.\w+([-.]\w+)*},
  message: "Please check and make sure you entered a valid email address."
}
```

We have determined that the validation code is not being called and that we are just assigning a value to the field we are checking.

We were finally able to get the code to work. The answer below was helpful but the test still failed. This is how we did it.

```
test "rejects invalid email" do
  addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
  addresses.each do |invalid_address|
    user = Jobboard.new(:email =>  invalid_address)
    user.valid?
    assert user.errors[:email].any?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
test "when email format is invalid" do
  addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
  addresses.each do |invalid_address|
   @jobboard.email= invalid_address
   @jobboard.valid?
   assert @jobboard.errors[:email].any?
  end
end
```

This is because until you called `valid?` or `save, update`, your validations will not kick off.

And from `@jobboard.errors[:email]`, you should be able to get the error message as well.

Comment: It responds with "Failed assertion, no message given. Is there a way to print out what is in :email when assert is checked?

Comment: message part should be not be inside the format hash `validates :email, allow_blank: true, format:{
  with: %r{\w+([+.']\w+)@\w+([.]\w+)\.\w+([-.]\w+)*} } ,
  message: "Please check and make sure you entered a valid email address."`, api - > http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of

Comment: to get the value in the email, its `@jobboard.email` :)